# How to draw/include ESD susceptibility symbol on my designs?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, orcad, allegro

I am using Allegro 16.6V.

I want to draw/include ESD susceptibility, non-recyclable and recyclable symbols on my design.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is on the PCB you want include the symbols.

You can make them as mechanical symbols and add the graphics there.

The symbols need to be prepared as BMP file in MS paint or something similar.

- Create a new mechanical symbol.
- Under the File->Import->Logo menu you can import a BMP file to the silkscreen layer.

[image: Logo import dialog]

- Select the correct file and click Import.
- Adjust location and scaling parameters. For smaller logo set scaling factor < 1
- Click Modify to apply changes.
- Click OK when done.

Save the symbol to your library.

Now you can add the symbol to your design by selecting Place->Mechanical symbols and choosing the correct symbol.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact steps? File->Import-> then ? Is it Artwork? Sub Drawing?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed procedure. I am able to bring the created mechanical symbols(logos) on to the board. Is there any way to make them smaller? They are bigger than my actual board size? Can u elaborate on the "scaling parameters" u mentioned?

Comment: Those scaling factors options are not visible on my window, may be it is in higher versions

Comment: @MightyBeard007. I use version 17.4